# ArgumentError: invalid radix -1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a `rails 3.2 , ruby 1.9.3` app
Trying to perform a simple `-1` action on an integer:
doing this on the model:

```
order_details[:quantity].to_i - 1
```

and getting the `ArgumentError: invalid radix -1`

Tried to look this up online , and found very little documentation.

Any help, pls?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming `order_details[:quantity]` is a `String` (though the answer is the same regardless).

[String#to_i](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_i) takes an optional argument for the base the number is to be interpreted as. For instance `"10101".to_i(2)` will parse as base 2, (giving the decimal `21` as a result). Your line of code is being interpreted as

```
order_details[:quantity].to_i(-1)
```

and since a base of negative one (`-1`) makes no sense, it's giving you that error. The solution is to put parentheses around `order_details[:quantity].to_i` so that it's evaluated first:

```
(order_details[:quantity].to_i) - 1
```

Edit:
Or, make sure there's a space separating `-` from the two arguments (or no spaces on either side) and Ruby should parse it correctly. It might be that your actual code is written as `order_details[:quantity].to_i -1` (note no space between `-` and `1`) causing it to read `-1` and then pass it as an argument to `to_i`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that your code really looks like this:

```
order_details[:quantity].to_i -1 # with the minus sign right next to the one
```

Ruby is parsing this as:

```
order_details[:quantity].to_i(-1)
```

Method parameters do not (always) need to be wrapped in parenthesis in Ruby, and `to_i` takes a parameter that specifies the base in which you are counting.

So you could convert base 16 into our normal base ten like:

```
"0xA".to_i(16)
```

iamnotmaynard correctly identified it as a syntax error, but I think it's that you need to separate the `-` and `1`. You could put parenthesis around the first element (it works), but that's more short-circuiting improper syntax instead of supplying proper syntax.

Try separating the elements out without parenthesis:

```
order_details[:quantity].to_i - 1 # with the space between the 1 and minus sign
```